# What are the names of all the books or subsections of the Tibetan Kangyur (and Tengyur)?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

From [AsianClassics.org](https://asianclassics.org/library/downloads/) you find downloadable copies of the Tibetan Kangyur and Tengyur. I have copied the Kangyur Table of Contents to a CSV [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/19b25b49f193b7020accf7a27f823de1). You'll notice many things are missing titles, some have titles in only Tibetan, etc.

Is there any standardized list of table of contents for the Tibetan Kangyur/Tengyur? Or why isn't there?

BTW what is the organization scheme they have going there anyways, with `KL00044-002(eTB)` and things like that?